# permutations with two groups recursive

Tags: python-3.x

I need a kick in the head on this problem(https://uchicago.kattis.com/problems/uchicago.shortmanhattan). I list the code I have written below. I know it looks terrible, but by now I can just reach so far. I just want to present what I am thinking about this problem.

```
def permunation_xy(x_move, y_move):
    if len(x_move) == 0 and len(y_move) >= 1:
        return y_move
    elif len(y_move) == 0 and len(x_move) >= 1:
        return x_move
    elif len(x_move) == 0 and len(y_move) == 0:
        return []

    else:
        [x_move[-1]] + permunation_xy(x_move[:-1], y_move) 
        [y_move[-1]] + permunation_xy(x_move, y_move[:-1])


x0, y0, x1, y1 = map(int, input().split())
x_move = []
y_move = []
if x0 == x1 and y0 == y1:
    print("NONE")
else:
    Dx = x1 - x0
    Dy = y1 - y0 
    if Dx > 0:
        x_move = ["right"] * abs(Dx)
    elif Dx < 0:
        x_move = ["left"] * abs(Dx)
    else:
        x_move = []
    if Dy > 0:
        y_move = ["up"] * abs(Dy)
    elif Dy < 0:
        y_move = ["down"] * abs(Dy)
    else:
        y_move =[]

    print(" ".join(permunation_xy(x_move, y_move)))
```

In this problem, how should i build a recursion process? how to deal with the multi outputs? I think this problem looks like building simple binary tree?

Beyond this problem, I am really depressed with recursive programming, I don't know how to think about them, don't know how to establish basic step, and recursive step. Can anyone share some experience with me? Thank you!